# Created MVC4 project and updated jquery - got "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

Created MVC4 project and updated jquery through Manage NuGet Packages to 1.7.1 - got "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"

I just created a new MVC4 project and did not change any line of code - updated jquery and now I am getting the error which I did not have before the update - should I go to previous version of jquery or it can be fixed?

I found the problem: jQuery.UI.Combined Version 1.8.17 - when I switch to 1.8.16 the problem got resolved

Comment: Nice statement, where's the detailed question?

Comment: Ok. And your question about that is...?

Comment: question is - I just created a new MVC4 project and did not change any line of code - just updated jquery and now I am getting the error which I did not have before the update - should I go to previous version of jquery or it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:
jQuery.UI.Combined Version 1.8.17 - when I switch to version 1.8.16 problem was resolved

jQuery UI (Combined Library) 1.8.18 (released 3/7/2012) - the issue fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can see the error in the console if you have Firebug installed, also you can use IE9 and open the developer tools and debug the script to see what's happening

Answer (score 1):

Add a semi-colon to the end of the jquery-ui-1.8.19.min.js file and it will fix the problem.